# Why does the cumulative distribution function for discrete random variable right continuous?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, cumulative-distribution-function

If the random variable is discrete, then the cumulative value should also be discrete because the variable can only take on discrete values, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No

The cumulative distribution function for a random variable $X$ supported on some subset of the real numbers can be defined as $$F(x)= \mathbb P(X \le x)$$ for all real $x$ whether $X$ is a discrete random variable or a continuous random variable or some mixture.  $F(x)$ is an increasing (perhaps weakly increasing) function of $x$ with $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}F(x) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}F(x) = 1$.

What is special about random variables which are wholly or partly discrete, i.e. with some $y$ where $\mathbb P(X = y)>0$ is that $F(x)$ is left-discontinuous at $y$ since $$F(y)-\lim\limits_{x \to y^{-}} F(x)= \mathbb P(X \le y) - \mathbb P(X \lt y) = \mathbb P(X = y)>0$$

But even here $F(x)$ is right-continuous at $y$ since $$\lim\limits_{x \to y^{+}} F(x) - F(y)= \lim\limits_{x \to y^{+}}\mathbb P(X \le x) - \mathbb P(X \le y) =\mathbb P(X \le y) - \mathbb P(X \le y) = 0$$

As an example, suppose $X$ takes the values $\pm3$ with equal probability so $\mathbb P(X =-3) = \mathbb P(X =3) =\frac12$. Then

$$F(x)=\mathbb P(X \le x) =\begin{cases} 
0 & \text{ when }x \lt 3\\
\frac12 & \text{ when }-3 \le x \lt 3\\
1 & \text{ when }3 \le x \\
\end{cases}$$

which is clearly right-continuous at $\pm3$ and also everywhere else.

Comment: I get it. The importance is that the CDF is defined on $$$\mathbb{R}$ but not the discrete points with an assigned value. Thank you so much.